# Has anyone gotten swank.rb working with Emacs 24?

Tags: ruby, emacs, slime

I've been looking for a SWANK server implementation for Ruby.

I found https://bitbucket.org/yinwm/usemacs/src/5bb82e78239c/raw-elisp/march/macos/site-lisp/slime/contrib/swank.rb but have had little luck making it play nice with Emacs 24 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Has anyone else had any luck?

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around the library it seems that it's not really complete. After tweaking the swank.rb code myself, I was able to get slime-connect to work. It needs quite a bit of polish to be a full-fledged swank server though.

Comment: did you push your version?